# iOS- make Segue perform after data is added to array (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, segue, urlsession

I'm attempting to perform a segue which passes an image array to a new view controller, but the segue is being performed before the images are added to the array- I believe this is because URLSession, which I'm using to convert a url to an image, takes time.

How would I have the Segue perform after the images are added to the array?

**My code where the url is turned into the image:**

```
// When selection is selected
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let overallArray = displayArray[indexPath.section]

    // Add Image 1 to imageArrayToBeSent
    if let imageUrl = overallArray.fullImage1 {
        let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageArrayToBeSent.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
            }

            }.resume()
    }

    // stringToBeSent = overallArray.fullImage1!
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "openNewViewController", sender: self)
}
```

**My code where I call the Segue:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 let info = segue.destination as! NewViewController
     info.imageArray = self.imageArrayToBeSent
    print(self.imageArrayToBeSent)
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it inside the callback

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.imageArrayToBeSent.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "openNewViewController", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Better to say "do it inside the completion handler for your dataTask, and inside the call to `DispatchQueue.main.async` that you already have in your completion handler. A completion handler is a lot like a callback, but using the right term will make your answer clearer. (voted anyway, since you showed the code.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Worked great.